# Any option to play audio from stream in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin

I was store audio recording in string using below code.

```
public static string ConvertToBase64(Stream stream)
{
    if (stream is MemoryStream memoryStream)
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
    }

    var bytes = new Byte[(int)stream.Length];

    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
}

var stream = audioRecorderService.GetAudioFileStream();

if (stream != null)
{
    visit.client_voice_record_data = ConvertToBase64(stream);
}
```

I want to retrieve this string to audio file but I am unable to do using this code.

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(visit.client_voice_record_data);

using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    _ = await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(stream);
}
```

Comment: `CrossMediaManager` doesn't have an overload that accepts a stream.  Why don't you just write it to a file?

Comment: SAP will work with a stream: https://github.com/adrianstevens/Xamarin-Plugins/tree/main/SimpleAudioPlayer#methods